# Static content not displaying after making django website live?

Tags: python, django

I hosted my website temporarily on pythonanywhere.com

But I don't understand why the static content is not being displayed. My settings.py on pythonanywhere.com is:

```
    STATIC_ROOT = u'/home/baqir/ProgrammersForum/main/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And on my localhost is:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Screenshot of pythonanywhere.com :

[image: Website live]

Screenshot on localhost:

[image: On localhost]

The urls are correct. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I also ran python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: Django does not like anything static in production, but you can get it to run by using `--insecure` when you start your server.

Comment: You mean `python manage.py --insecure`?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver x.x.x.x --insecure`. However this is a bad idea for production.

Comment: @GreenSaber you shouldn't even have mentioned it in this context. `runserver` has nothing to do with production.

Comment: @BaqirKhan did you read the documentation about deploying static files, or any of the other hundreds of questions on exactly the same issue?

Comment: Yeah all I could find was to set the static root and run collectstatic. I did it.

Comment: Check out this help page: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles -- in particular, the "Set up a static files mapping" section.

Answer (score -1):

Make these changes.

```
Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[Django Official Documentation Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: Where? in settings.py?

Comment: This answer is erroneous, the instructions are for Apache rather than for PythonAnywhere.